# How can I make my API date field to be 3 business days from today's date taking weekends (Sat and Sun) into account using JS?

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript for to communicate with platform's api. Just have a quick question!

There is a date picker which you can click and pick any date. My task here is to build a JS code that can communicate with the Date variable and won't let it select a date more than 3 business days for e.g: today is 22/04 and the max one can select is 25/04. I have already built this code which you can see below.

My questions is how I can take weekends into account in this code? Like if Sat/Sun falls within then they won't be counted. Only business days will be counted!

Any assistance will be highly appreciated!

**Code snippet:**

````
const DateVar = "DATE"; /* name of the date variable in Checkbox to apply validation to */

events[`change:${DateVar}`] = async () => {


    const days = 3; /* how many days from today the user is able to select dates*/

    const today = new Date();

    let validationPeriodStart = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate() + days));

    /* VALIDATION FUNCTION */

    const result = form.ShowCustomValidation(DateVar, [(value) => {

        /* transform the selected date into JS Date object */
        const selectedDate = new Date(value);

        /* validate if the selected date is before the period where user can select dates (today + 3 weeks and onward) */

        const RESULT = value && selectedDate < validationPeriodStart ?
            `Error: Please make sure your date is after the ${validationPeriodStart.toLocaleDateString('en-SG')}` : undefined;

        return RESULT;

    }
    ]);

    /* throw a pop-up error in the top right corner - remove if not required */
    if (result) { form.SetError(result) };

};

addEvents(events);```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A full-fledged solution would take into account holidays of fixed and variable dates and thus be highly dependent on precise geolocation data. A less picky solution would harvest holiday databases for relevant locales compiling local calendar data structures comprising a holiday flag.

For the basic step of excluding Sat/sun, use the `Date.getDay()` method.

The following sample code (replace you code line let validationPeriodStart = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate() + days));`` with it) defines a current date and advances it in steps of 1 day, each turn testing for Saturday/Sunday, until the datetime horizon is exhausted. Computations are performed in the domain of the epoch defined by milliseconds since 1970/01/01.

```
let d_current = new Date()
  , n_horizonDistance = days
  , validationPeriodStart 
  ;
while (n_horizonDistance > 0) {
    let n_dow = d_current.getDay()
      ;
    if ((n_dow !== 0) && (n_dow !== 6)) {
        n_horizonDistance--;
    }
    d_current = new Date(d_current.getTime() + 1000 * 3600 * 24); // + 1 day
}
```

The method caters for month and year spillovers (including leap years) but not for DST. It can easily be extended, eg. checking for holidays. Consult [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for more info on the JS `Date` object and its features.

More flexibility and cleaner code and is achieved by precomputing the cutoff dates for a certain period of time and store the data in the server-side db.